# Spam getting through simple spam filter, but I don't know how

Tags: html, forms, filter, spam

I have a simple spam filter (to prevent spam form submission) setup on a website by generating a random number and having the user enter it in. For some reason spam is still able to get through without even entering the random number. Does anyone have any ideas as to how this could be happening?

Here's the code:

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*1001);
var isNumberEnteredCorrect = false;
var whatevertheyentered;


function checkUserInput(whatevertheyentered){

if(whatevertheyentered == randomnumber){
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}

function validateForm()
{
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["random_number"].value;

  if(x == randomnumber){
    return true;
  }

  else{
    alert("The number you've entered is incorrect.");
    return false;
  }


}
```

The user submits the form by pressing this button:

```
 <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message" />
```

Comment: Why is the `else` commented out in `validateForm()`?

Comment: Sorry, it's not commented out, I just copied it wrong.

Comment: Users can disable javascript. So they can get around this spam filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On of the options, why spam bots are getting trough is that they don't use JavaScript and do direct submissions of the form.

One of the options, though is to send form asynchronously with AJAX. It would probably save you from some of the bots (and users, who have JavaScript disabled).

I don't know how spam bots internal logic, but I assume that that the bot searches for "form" tag and tries to post form contents to the form's action parameter.
It this case "split-string encoding" of action form parameter and AJAX form submission might help.

However, keep in mind, that this trick will work only if your's site is not primary target for the bots.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any immediate errors with you javascript, however, any user can disable javascript in their browser so these functions would not execute. Because of this you should not rely of just javascript for form validation. Backing it up with a server side language such as PHP is much safer.

Comment: The problem with that though, is that I don't have PHP on my server, which is outside of my control, because it's my employer's. Are there any other anti-spam methods I could use that don't use PHP?

Comment: @user: Sure, if they use ASP.net.  Or if they use, i dunno, Perl.  But you need some kind of server-side code.  Anything on the client side can be forged, faked, disabled, or otherwise gotten around.

Answer (score 0):

Do server-side validation with PHP/ASP.NET/ColdFusion or whatever you're using. NEVER rely entirely on client-side validation, it's the most prone to hacking and abuse.

Once the form is filled out, the values should be sent to, say, a review.php page where you check that the value was that which you were expecting. If correct, proceed normally, else end the execution of the form/submission code and redirect users to an error page of sorts.

Comment: Just let us know what 'languages' you do have access to

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript to submit your form that way if a bot has JS disabled it cannot submit the form.